# Why does set.average return a different value than array.average?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, set, average

I was tinkering around with my IDE and I stumbled across something interesting. Check out this code:

```
val arr1 = intArrayOf(3, 3, 2)
val set1 = setOf(3, 3, 2)

println(arr1.average())
println(set1.average())
```

These appear pretty similar, but it returns this:

```
2.6666666666666665
2.5
```

Why are these returning different values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/):

> [A set is] A generic unordered collection of elements that does not support duplicate elements.

This means that even though you're initializing a set as `{3, 3, 2}`, it's actually `{3, 2}`. The average of `{3, 2}` is 2.5.